# Is there any way to get navigationBarBackgroundView and statusBarBackgroundView?

Tags: android

I'm trying to get those 2 views for adjustment layout height purpose. I've tried many ways to get but all return **null**

```
getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground);
```

I also put the breakpoint at the method `getChildCount()` but there is only 1 child inside.

```
try {
    FrameLayout rootView = (FrameLayout) getWindow().getDecorView();
    Log.i("MainAct", "getChildCount = " + rootView.getChildCount()); //only 1 child is the LinearLayout
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to get the views from the activity?  
`View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();`

Comment: @MarcoCarrizales actually i write the code `getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground);` inside the **onCreate()** method of my Activity, but it return **null**, i also try it in **onStart()**, **onResume()**, **onPostResume()** but same results (**null**)